# How to determine whether a smart contract implements an interface or not?

Tags: solidity

Is there some way to determine, within a smart contract, whether the address supplied as a parameter in a function call refers to a smart contract, and further whether the contract referred to implements a particular interface, or responds to a particular function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I check if an address refers to a smart contract?**

There isn't a safe way to check if an address corresponds to a contract or not. You could use this assembly code to check the **CODESIZE**

```
function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
  uint size;
  assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
  return size > 0;
}
```

but that is not safe because it will return `false` if the function is called from the constructor of the smart contract you are checking.
You can check this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644395/how-to-find-out-if-an-ethereum-address-is-a-contract

**Can I check if a smart contract fits with some interface?**

No, you can't. Interfaces and methods call are just syntactic sugar provided in compilation time, so you don't have to craft the message data by yourself, but there is no information about the smart contract interface at bytecode level.

Answer (score 1):

you can you ERC165Storage and ERC165Checker to verify that a contract uses a specific interface.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/introspection#ERC165Checker

https://github.com/binodnp/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/docs/ERC165Checker.md

Comment: This only works when smart contracts implement the ERC165 standard.